# How do I find out why file I/O operations fail?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Several methods I've used to write to files return a BOOL signifying their success, e.g.

NSDictionary:

```
- (BOOL) writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

NSKeyedArchiver:

```
- (BOOL) archiveRootObject:(id)rootObject toFile:(NSString *)path
```

Somehow, this returned NO on one of my tester's devices.  That's great (well, not really), but is there anyway to find out *why* these operations might have failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modern way is to create NSData from the (root object|dictionary), then write that data to the desired path using `writeToFile:options:error:` or `writeToURL:options:error:`. These methods return an NSError object by reference, which contains a description of what happened, including (in at least some cases) a user-presentable error message.

To create data representing a dictionary, use `NSPropertyListSerialization` (if the dictionary and all of its contents, all the way down, are a valid [property list](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html)) or the archiver (if not).